# Java - Highlighter sigue resaltando luego de la ultima palabra en JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

Estoy creando un programa en java que resalta los errores ortograficos en base a un diccionario previamente cargado. Lo que estoy intentando de hacer es ir resaltando los errores a medida que el usuario va escribiendo en un JTextArea, mi problema es que cuando termina de escribir la ultima palabra y se presiona el espacio o un enter se acciona un evento que analiza la ultima palabra, que fue obtenida a traves de un DocumentListener, y si esta no esta en el diccionario la resalta pero despues si sigo escribiendo sin corregir el error, se me resalta todo lo que escribo despues de esa palabra, y yo solo quiero que solo resalte la palabra si esta esta mal y luego siga normal sin resaltar y que si encuentra otra palabra con error que la resalte. Para obtener el inicio y el fin de la ultima palabra uso la clase Utilities en el DocumentEvent.

private class EventoDocumento implements DocumentListener, KeyListener{
        private int start;
        private int end;
        private String palabra;

```
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        chequearPalabra();

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        chequearPalabra();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {

    }

    private void chequearPalabra(){
        try {
            start = Utilities.getWordStart(texto, texto.getCaretPosition());
            end = Utilities.getWordEnd(texto, texto.getCaretPosition());
            palabra = texto.getDocument().getText(start, end-start);
            errores.setText(palabra);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            if(!Revisor.getTrie().buscar(palabra.toUpperCase())){
                System.out.println(Revisor.getTrie().buscar(palabra.toUpperCase()));
                resaltarPalabra(start, start+palabra.length());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @FDarfe, añade algún código de ejemplo para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Ahi agregue la parte del codigo que se encarga de determinar la ultima palabra del texto y resaltarla si es que no esta en el diccionario.